# Inference mechanism on collaborative knowledgebase (Freebase)?

Tags: freebase, inference

Freebase is probably the awesomest collaborative knowledge base available. Does anybody know if its powerful api provide some inference drawing mechanism? If not can any one point me to some example that fetches data from freebase and does some inferencing (for checking facts about "stuff")? Should I concentrate on building the more complex queries or pull out the [AIMA](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu) book and try to [use](http://code.google.com/p/aima-python/) forward chaining, backward chaining, resolution etc with data obtained by search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Freebase APIs and the MQL query language don't have any inferencing capabilities built in. However, MQL allows developers to create their own [extensions to the query language](http://www.freebase.com/docs/mql_extensions/common) and many of the [current extensions](http://www.freebase.com/docs/mql_extensions/.people.person.age) do provide limited forms of inference.

Of course, you could also just load the [Freebase data dumps](http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/latest/) as [RDF](http://code.google.com/p/freebase-quad-rdfize/) into a tuple store that supports more powerful methods of inference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It would be great if you could recommend some such tuple stores with "powerful methods of inference". Are things like Jena(http://jena.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) apt for such tasks?

Comment: Tools like Jena should work just fine. The only thing to watch out for is that the Freebase data dumps can get pretty large. So make sure that you either have a lot of RAM, use a triple store that stores to disk or only load a subset of the Freebase data. http://www.w3.org/wiki/LargeTripleStores

Answer (score 0):

Load the RDF dump (only the full dataset seems available now from google) and run the inference in a specific graph.